# JS Regex to remove IMG Tag from String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String from a tabel innerHTML where i need to remove all img tags using `replace` my Regex removes everthing after the first img tag my code at JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mhzkncec/)

Comment: Do post what you have tried.

Comment: If you're getting this string from a table's `.innerHTML` property anyway - it's much better if you do this removal using DOM methods instead - don't try to do it with regex.

Comment: why is it better with dom?

Comment: because [regex is bad for parsing html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3702797) (except few rare cases)

Comment: you're performing an operation on a DOM string, why wouldn't use DOM methods - plus regex sux at HTML

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use non-greedy matching using `.*?`

```
var tmp = inner.replace(/<img .*?>/g,"REPLACED");
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tG1iO0/1)

Comment: Doing this kind of thing with regex is not reliable. For example, this would trip up on something like `<img src='file.jpg' alt='Three > Two'>`

Comment: @DalHundal I agree. I was just pointing out why *Regex removes everthing after the first img tag*